# Image change validation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I want to change the image in validation like if the text field is empty the image color is grey  or if filled the circle is green color.

I have tried this in button action-

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a_image.png"];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: I don't see anything having to do with color in that snippet.

Comment: sorry for my mistake... i want to change image

Comment: can u please help me how to change image when i enter some value in textbox... thnx in advnce.

Comment: do you want to change imgageView Color or image ?

Comment: i want to change image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your button action.

```
  if (self.MyTextField.text.length!=0)
        self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"redImage"];
    else
        self.MyImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenImage"];
```

If you want to change colour when user is typing in text field, use following delegate method of textfield to do any stuff.

> -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

Comment: thnx...but i want to do that when u enter some text in textbox the image is automatically change with out button action.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple:

```
if (textField.text.length == 0){
   //Do something if its empty
} else {
   //Do something else if its not
}
```

EDIT: If you want to do this on the fly and not when they're done editing you could do something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)textChanged
{
    if (self.textField.text.length == 0) {
        self.someVIew.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    } else if (self.textField.text.length > 5){
        self.someVIew.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.someVIew.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ria simply set the imageView.image property within the if statement to whichever image you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];

if (textField.text.length == 0){
   imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImage.png"];
} else {
   imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImage.png"];
}
```